# php-fpm + bindfs not working

Tags: php, ubuntu, bind, apache2.4

I'm trying to setup my local web server using vagrant. My vagrant shared folder is in my home folder (~/home/vagrant/www) and I want to use bindfs to mount this folder inside /var/www.

These are the specs of my virtual machine:

- Apache/2.4.23 (Ubuntu)
- PHP 7.0.12
- Ubuntu 14.04

I am using php-fpm to execute php scripts but after using bindfs, my site will always return **File not found.**

Also here is my virtualhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project1.dev

    ## Vhost docroot
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/project1/public"

    ## Directories, there should at least be a declaration for /var/www/project1/public

   <Directory "/var/www/project1/public">
       Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted

       <FilesMatch "\.php$">
          Require all granted
          SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
       </FilesMatch>

   </Directory>

   ## Logging
   ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/av_anhk5lpgjldb_error.log"
   ServerSignature Off
   CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/av_anhk5lpgjldb_access.log" combined

   ## Server aliases 
   ServerAlias www.project1.dev

   ## SetEnv/SetEnvIf for environment variables
   SetEnv APP_ENV dev
   SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

   ## Custom fragment
</VirtualHost>
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to successfully run php-fpm + bindfs in my virtual machine. I just made sure that user who is running php-fpm and apache are the one I set in my bindfs command. My apache is run by `www-user` so I change my command to `sudo bindfs -o perms=0755,mirror-only=www-user,force-group=www-data,force-user=www-user /home/vagrant/www /var/www` and made sure that apache is also run by `www-user`.